# Sending iAuditor data to a Sharepoint Online 2013 list and or library

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, web-services, csv

We are seriously considering using iAuditor on all our mobile devices to capture QA reports and other audits.

We would like to know if it is possible to develop a Web Service that will

- import a csv file and add items to a custom list.
- The originating data may also contain photos.
- The data will be exported as both a csv and PDF.

Ideally the list item would contain a link to the PDF document which contains photos. Data will be coming from mobile devices via the `iAuditor App`. We would like this data presented in a dashboard type environment where we could produce filtered results in list form and possibly graphs etc…

Comment: Also interested in this, be interested if anyone replies.

Answer (score 0):

Caveat: I am not a member of *SafetyCulture* or the people that made **iAuditor**

We had the same requirement, and until recently, you **could not do** the above in prior older versions of iAuditor. Now with Sharepoint Online, MS Flow and the new iAuditor you can, but at a price!

There are examples and tutorials on the following link:

https://support.safetyculture.com/reports/automatically-export-audits-with-ms-flow/

and some of the features and reviews from other users:

https://www.getapp.com/operations-management-software/a/iauditor/features/

In a nutshell, you have to purchase the iAuditor Sharepoint API, which does not come with iAuditor on its own. Also, you have to add the API to an MS Flow to make it produce the PDFs, when and where you want, based on triggers from MS Flow.

All of the mobile iAuditor data is automatically attached, as long as the reports are done online and in realtime. All you have to do is assign the flow of that data as per the above tutorials.